# How to access text field using selenium when main identifiers are auto-generated

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table which outputs some data on each row and for each row includes a text field. I have a separate dataframe with values I need to input into the relevant row but I can't figure out how to get the correct text input element as the name isn't unique.

I can get the element which contains `123456/1` so I can find the row containing the PartA I want but I can't figure out how to get the text input field id="VALUE.ENTER.SYSTEM.1-XY that then corresponds to that row. `.XY` is a number value that changes depending on the number of rows of data and **I can't assume that a particular value of XY corresponds to the value I want to look for.**

I don't know the full @value for the row and the values listed on the page is limited to 50 at a time so just because I don't find it once doesn't mean it won't appear on a later page. I need to find the 1st row in the table, extract a value from it and then if I have a match in another dataframe, if I do I want to add a value to the text box at the end of the row before moving on to the next row and repeating the `extract`, `compare`, `submit` steps until I run out of rows

Any reliable way to locate the text input field in python that has

> title ="EnterValueHere"

**My Code**

```
for row in rows:
    RowData = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")
    for cell in RowData:
        #Get the ID in question
        if "/" in cell.get_attribute("value"):
            TextToSplit =cell.get_attribute("value")
            PartA,PartB= str(TextToSplit).split("/")
            print(PartA)
```

**Sample Table**

```
  <tr>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  <input type="hidden" name="UNIQUE_ID.SYSTEM.01" value="12">
                  <input type="hidden" name="HEADER_ID.SYSTEM.01" value="">
                  123456/1<input type="hidden" name="CODE.SYSTEM.01" value="123456/1">
                  <span id="ANCHOR.SYSTEM.01"></span>
                </td>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  BLOGGS JOE<input type="hidden" name="NAME.SYSTEM.01" value="JOE BLOGGS">
                </td>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  1<input type="hidden" name="ATTEMPT.SYSTEM.01" value="1">
                </td>

                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="PRODUCTID.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-12" value="XY1234+1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="SUS_CODE.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-12" value="">

                  <div class="sv-input-group-table"><div class="sv-input-group"><span class="sv-input-group-addon"><span class="mme-input-group">

                   N<input type="hidden" name="RTS_CODE.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-12" value="N">
                  </span></span><input type="text" class="sv-form-control sv-form-control-xs" name="VALUE.ENTER.SYSTEM.1-12" id="VALUE.ENTER.SYSTEM.1-12" title="EnterValueHere" value=""></div></div>
                  <span class="fbk-input-group fbk-select"></span>
                </td>


</tr>
<tr>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  <input type="hidden" name="UNIQUE_ID.SYSTEM.02" value="12">
                  <input type="hidden" name="HEADER_ID.SYSTEM.02" value="">
                  123456/1<input type="hidden" name="CODE.SYSTEM.02" value="234456/1">
                  <span id="ANCHOR.SYSTEM.02"></span>
                </td>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  BLOGGS JOE<input type="hidden" name="NAME.SYSTEM.02" value="J BLOGGS">
                </td>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  1<input type="hidden" name="ATTEMPT.SYSTEM.02" value="1">
                </td>

                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="PRODUCTID.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-02" value="XY1234+2">
                  <input type="hidden" name="SUS_CODE.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-02" value="">

                  <div class="sv-input-group-table"><div class="sv-input-group"><span class="sv-input-group-addon"><span class="mme-input-group">

                   N<input type="hidden" name="RTS_CODE.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-02" value="N">
                  </span></span><input type="text" class="sv-form-control sv-form-control-xs" name="VALUE.ENTER.SYSTEM.1-02" id="VALUE.ENTER.SYSTEM.1-02" title="EnterValueHere" value=""></div></div>
                  <span class="fbk-input-group fbk-select"></span>
                </td>


 </tr>
 <tr>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  <input type="hidden" name="UNIQUE_ID.SYSTEM.03" value="12">
                  <input type="hidden" name="HEADER_ID.SYSTEM.03" value="">
                  123456/1<input type="hidden" name="CODE.SYSTEM.03" value="56789/1">
                  <span id="ANCHOR.SYSTEM.02"></span>
                </td>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  BLOGGS JOE<input type="hidden" name="NAME.SYSTEM.03" value="JM BLOGGS">
                </td>
                <td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">
                  1<input type="hidden" name="ATTEMPT.SYSTEM.03" value="1">
                </td>

                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="PRODUCTID.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-03" value="XY1234+2">
                  <input type="hidden" name="SUS_CODE.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-03" value="">

                  <div class="sv-input-group-table"><div class="sv-input-group"><span class="sv-input-group-addon"><span class="mme-input-group">

                   N<input type="hidden" name="RTS_CODE.DUM_ASSESSMENT.MENSYS.1-02" value="N">
                  </span></span><input type="text" class="sv-form-control sv-form-control-xs" name="VALUE.ENTER.SYSTEM.1-03" id="VALUE.ENTER.SYSTEM.1-03" title="EnterValueHere" value=""></div></div>
                  <span class="fbk-input-group fbk-select"></span>
                </td>


 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

So first you need to get the TR for your code `123456/1`. The xpath would be

```
//tr[td//input[@name="CODE.SYSTEM.XY"][@value=123456/1]
```

So above is to get the `tr` element which contains your `input` element. Now you want the input to be located inside this tr, which can be done by extending the XPath to

```
//tr[td//input[@name="CODE.SYSTEM.XY"][@value=123456/1]/td//input[@title='EnterValueHere']
```

**Updated-1: 30th May 2018**

You should use

```
//tr[td//input[starts-with(@name, 'CODE.SYSTEM.')][starts-with(@value, '123456/')]/td//input[@title='EnterValueHere']
```

> the first section says find a tr anywhere in the document
>   then [] condition says which has an element td and child input field anywhere hwre
>   which as attribute name starting with CODE.... and value starting 12345/
>   once the tr is found
>   find another td inside that which has an input with title entervaluehere

Comment: I have the code above already that gets me the TR but are you saying its possible to use the title as a way to find the text field? Can you explain what your 2nd line of code means

Comment: You should not use that code. You should use the XPath to get the input in one go

Comment: But I don't know the full @value for the row and the values listed on the page is limited to 50 at a time so just because I don't find it once doesn't mean it won't appear on a later page. I need to find the 1st row, extract a value from it and then if I have a match I want to add a value to the text box at the end of the row before moving on to the next row and so on until I run out of rows

Comment: Can you add example of 3 rows to the example and then explain the situation, its better to be on same page before I update my solution

Comment: updated the question and added some more sample rows

Comment: What reference value from the row do you know before hand?

Comment: My code above gets the value which contains "/" and splits using the "/" character as I need the left hand side of the value to search a different dataset to find the value I need to enter into the text box

Comment: So in case of `value="234456/1"` you already know that you are looking for value with `234456` before `/`?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to target the correct text box because I don't want the value I enter for `234456` ending up in the text box in the row for `123456` or vis versa

Comment: You can use this xpath then `//tr[td//input[@name='CODE.SYSTEM.XY'][starts-with(@value, '123456/')]/td//input[@title='EnterValueHere']`, and you will replace the value `123456` dynamically to create the xpath for value you are looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171760/discussion-between-mobcdi-and-tarun-lalwani).